# Mathieu Crickboom "The violin" method

Tags: strings, violin, string-instruments, teaching

My teacher insist on teaching Mathieu Crickboom's `The violin` books. `The violin` has 5 volumes. it usually take 5 years for 5 volumes.

- I don't know is it good method?
- what's the most famous method for teaching violin?(or what's some experts suggest.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

.To your question "is it good method?" I would say there are different "schools", different ideals of how to work repertoire, bowing and holding. The European and Russian schools being the biggest.

Mathieu Crickboom was a great violinist who played with for example Pablo Casals.

His books are good. More important is the guidance you have of your teacher thru them.

I would say other famous violin methods/teaching books are `Dont`, `Schradieck`, `Kreutzer`, `Sevcik` and `Mazas`, ammong others, Some are more "hardcore" technique, others are more melodie &/or harmony focused, and of course (even not being a "method") `Bach`'s Sonatas & Partittas is a very important book to develop in playing, intonation and doubble stops.

Again, `Mathieu`'s book is good. If you want hardcore go to `Schradiek` , if you like more melody/harmony studies with technique inside take `Dont`.

Comment: nice answer, is there any document that describe each method in more detail?

Comment: This is a very interesting discussion, specially if together with violin pedagogy. Although it is often a conversation subject I am not aware or literature or academic textes comparing different methods.

Comment: @ArashMousavi, found this link that might fit your question also. http://speedyviolinlessons.com/members/wp-content/uploads/2010/05/Violin-Mastery-Ebook.pdf

Comment: Great answer. It would be even more useful if you could include their strengths and weaknesses with your list of methods.

Answer (score 2):

I think the method, be it what it is, is just content to practice.

The real guidance is the teacher.

However, a great method is one that surrounds all the core techniques that are stacked on upon the other, meaning if you play lesson A good you're ready to go to lesson B, but more important is, especially for beginners, is that level 100 in the book covers only the very basic stuff.
IMHO, a method that spends many lessons on the boring core whole notes stuff, will make you a better violin, since when you play fast music you don't really pay attention to the negligible things in intonation, bowing, arm and finger movement, and more.
I've been exploring many methods and one of the methods I've found to be very throughout that when achieved leaves you with a very good technique disregarding the genre or style you play, is from a Hungarian violinist, conductor and teacher *Frigyes Sándor* (1905-1979). The method is relatively rare but I found it to be very efficient. It concentrates on every technique spending many lessons on each aspect, after completion you're technique basis is really solid.

[image]